# how do I list all the records of one model to be selected in a second model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on rails 4.

I have one model `features` that has a list of records only createable by me. I have another model `houses` that users can create.

I want to list all of the `features` as checkboxes in the form for a new `house` so the users can choose which ones they want attached to their `house`. I also have a connecting model `house_features` that associates the two because many `houses` can have many different `features`.

My `house` model:

```
has_many :house_features, dependent: :destroy
has_many :features, through: :house_features
accepts_nested_attributes_for :house_features
```

My `feature` model:

```
has_many :house_features
has_many :houses, through: :house_features
```

My `house_feature` model:

```
belongs_to :house
belongs_to :feature
```

In my new `house` form I have

```
<%= form_for @house do |f| %>
<% Features.all.each do |feature| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :house_features do |h| %>
    <%= h.label :feature_id, feature.name %>
    <%= h.check_box :feature_id, {}, feature.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my `houses` controller I have a `@house.house_features.build` in my new action and I have the house_params set to `house_features_attributes: [:id, :house_id, :feature_id]

Now, on the new `house` page, The list of `feature` record checkboxes show up. If I select some and submit the form and then go back to edit the house, I end up having a bunch of extra checkboxes for each `feature` listed and the number of check boxes corresponds with the amount of features I chose when creating it.

Why is this happening? Would should I do/change to fix this issue?

I want my users to be able to edit their houses and add or remove features.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have redundant loop:

```
<%= f.fields_for :house_features do |h| %>
```

You should rewrite your loops to use only one loop and select checkboxes which selected for this `house`:

```
<%= form_for @house do |f| %>
  <% Features.all.each do |feature| %>
    <%= h.label :feature_id, feature.name %>
    <%= h.check_box :feature_id, {checked: @house.house_features.include?(feature)}, feature.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, This make the multiple checkbox problem on the edit page go away, however, with this the house_feature record does not get created, so nothing is saved.